# Inverted color cursor with custom shape

Tags: colors, desktop-customization, cursor

**TL;DR** Is there a way to have a custom (preferably tailless) cursor with inverted colors on Windows 10?

I really like using the inverted color cursor on Windows 10, so that the color of the cursor is always the opposite of what the cursor is on:
(Settings>Easy of access>Mouse Pointer)

[image]

However I really hate the shape of the default cursor, I mostly like tailless cursors. There are plenty of custom cursors (e.g. in devianart, or some on github) out there:

[image]

However I can't seem to find any custom cursor with inverted colors, and I have no idea if it is an easy task to take the cursor files and modify them. Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You need a program [that can edit cursor files](https://www.codeitbro.com/best-custom-cursor-maker-software/).

Within any cursor program (that doesn't suck), you will find the option to add "inverted" as an option just like transparent is an option for a color.

The built in cursor files are questionably not editable legally so I will not tell you how to do that but you will find free equivalents all over the internetz.

You can even add super spiffo animations to them to using many of the programs listed in the first link.  This was all the rage in the windows 9x days.